# Calling python scripts too many times in C++ casuse Too Many open file error

Tags: python, c++

I'm using jtop package in python to get computer status infomation. I need those infomation every 3 seconds. So I call the python script every 3 seconds.

Here is my C++ code:

```cpp
int get_jtop_info()
{
    char *ret_str = NULL;
    PyThreadStateLock lock; //get python GIL lock
    try
    {
        PyObject* pModule = NULL;
        PyObject* pFunc =NULL;
        PyObject* pRet =NULL;
        pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("calculation");
        if (pModule==NULL) {
            return NO_SUCH_FILE;
        }
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "get_calculation_info");
        if(!pFunc||!PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            return NO_SUCH_ITEM;    
        }
        pRet = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
        PyArg_Parse(pRet,"s", &ret_str);
        if(pRet) Py_DECREF(pRet);
        if(pModule) Py_DECREF(pModule);
        if(pFunc) Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        PyErr_Clear();
    }

    if(ret_str) {
        // process return valuse
    }

    return 1;
}
```

After the program run 80 minutes, I got Too Many open file error. I found the program once called the python script, the number of files opened by the program will increase. If I do not call python script, the number of files opened by the program does not change. And no file is opened in my python script.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does calling a python script once in c++ open many files？
2. How can I release those files or close them?

Comment: If you return early with `NO_SUCH_ITEM` then you forget to `Py_DECREF(pModule)`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `NULL` is the old C macro for null-pointers. In C++ use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: As for a way to figure out your problem, begin by commenting out *everything*. If it then start to work good. Uncomment the `PyImport_ImportModule` call (and its corresponding `Py_DECREF` call). Do you still run out of files? No? Then uncomment `PyObject_GetAttrString` (and its `Py_DECREF`). And lastly `PyObject_CallObject`. This will help you pinpoint the problem. Oh, and change your code to call this script multiple times per second instead, so you don't have to wait 80 minutes (or find another way to monitor file handles/descriptors).

Comment: You need to elaborate on your architecture. Are you embedding Python interpreter? You mean jtop for jetson-stats? What's the proof that your module and all of the 3rd party modules you are using do not open any file?